Looking for feedback for student profile design
I am very new in UI Design and for a project I recently created a design for a student profile page and I'm looking for some feedback on how to enhance it. The page is meant to display a student's general information, identity details, and school info. I've attached an image of the current design for reference.

UPDATE version 2
So still trying to improve, I came up with a different approach :

So the idea is for the user when he opens a student profile page, he sees quickly these informations without needing to scroll down or click on a button.
I use Tailwind and simple html and js, nothing more. The design is for school staff for their intern student management tool.
Do the blue and yellow colors work well together? Is there a better combination for blue that would make the page more visually appealing?
My own critics : We don't see the text easily, the fonts needs a better contrast so it can be viewed on background items for example. What I like : the sections in each panel so that the info is organized
I appreciate any advice or suggestions you can offer to make this design better!
Thanks you all

Hi, Welcome to GDSE. The main issue I see here is with the contrast of the white text on the yellow background, and the grey text on the blue background which is almost unreadable.

Hi, thank you for welcoming me and for the feedback. You're right I thought about it also and I think a white with dark shadow would help ? What you think ?

usually open ended questions such as "can anything else be improved?" or "any suggestions" end up closed as too broad. Better [edit] the question to focus to get more objective answers.

Please edit your question to follow our critique guidelines or your question is likely to be closed

question edited

I'm not posting this as an answer, because it's just my opinion. But here's what I think. In your edit, the white text on blue background is still problematic, especially for the smaller white text.  Also, I think you need to work on your English as it's a little odd. Are these direct translations from French? Note that Roominfo is not a word in English, and "Birthplace" is one word.  "Mail" should be "E-mail".   The sentences beginning "Retrieve here all the . . ." are non-native word order.  I don't think you need the word "Info" in the section titles as it's redundant.

Thank you for your feedback on ui and for the english corrections
